# I want to type HTML commands in an HTML file so that they are displayed as text on the webpage instead of browser taking them as tags

Tags: html

For example is I type `<ul>` then it should be displayed in browser.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: Are you asking for a [real-time editor](http://htmledit.squarefree.com/)?

Comment: This is very unclear. HTML doesn't have commands. And questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I am taking notes in an HTML class and saving them in an HTML file in the form of a webpage so when my teacher is teaching the meaning and usage of different tags then  if i use the paragraph tag then my browser takes it as code so what i want is the tag should be displayed in browser on the webpage

Comment: @tobey are you asking about how to escape characters, as with `&gt;` for `>`?

Comment: If I understand your question you want something like this:

`<p>hi&lt;div&gt;</p>` which give as output `hi<div>`